# GameScene.sks file is not being used

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm learning Swift and I'm starting with SpriteKit.
I'm trying to create a simple game, and got a question about how SpriteKit works. I made a new scene (MenuScene) with a start button, I edited the `GameViewController.swift` to run `MenuScene` first.
on `MenuScene`, I'm moving to `GameScene` which is linked to `GameScene.sks`. When I run the application, It "ignores" `GameScene.sks` and not displaying anything from there.
When I'm editing the `GameViewController.swift` to run `GameScene` first I can see everything I added to GameScene. Why is that happening? Hope I'm clear enough, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not the EXACT answer you're looking for but it will work (unless I'm misinterpreting your question). I generally tend to find it's better to load a scene from its .swift file rather than the .sks file (which I don't use at all). An easy way to do this is:

```
func loadGameScene() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    let transitionType = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
    let skView1 = view as! SKView
    skView1.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    skView1.presentScene(scene,transition: transitionType)
}
```

You can put this function in your GameViewController, and call it from GameViewController whenever you click the button. If you really want to use your .sks file you can just edit this function to use your .sks instead.

If you don't know how to call that function from another SKScene class(MenuScene), this is how you do it:

In your Scene, create a variable `viewController` like so:

```
class MenuScene: SKScene{

    var viewController: GameViewController!
```

This points to your GameViewController. Now in your GameViewController, right after presenting the MenuScene, add:

`scene.viewController = self`

Now in your MenuScene you can just call `viewController.loadGameScene()` to switch the scenes

Comment: I tried this, I didn't get exactly what is "view" in this code, and I get a problem ( something about downcast ) in this line ( let skView1 = xxxxx ). Thanks!

Comment: @swiftnewbie are you putting it in your GameViewController.swift file? Also make sure it's within the brackets of the class

Comment: where should I call this function ? I'm now moving to GameScene from MenuScene, Can I call it from MenuScene?

Comment: @swiftnewbie I'll add that part into the answer hold on

Comment: @swiftnewbie ok it's added

Comment: @MarshallID Thanks!